# Make significant effects in table appear bold in final pfd document

Tags: r, r-markdown, papaja

I am working in RMarkdown and trying to get significant effects in my Anova table appear bold in the final pdf document. In this instance, the row that needs to be bold is the second row of the table (with the column names being the first row).

Using *papaja* package: [link to GitHub](https://github.com/crsh/papaja)

This is how I conducted the Anova

```r
library(apaTables)
library(MOTE)
data("iris")
ManCheck2.1 <- aov(formula = Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width * Petal.Length, data = iris) 
ManCheck2.1APA <- apa_print(ManCheck2.1)
```

This is what I did to prepare the detailed table

```r
M2 <- apa.aov.table(ManCheck2.1, conf.level = .95)
M2table <- M2$table_body
# Delete the "(Intercept)" line:
M2table <- M2table[-1, ]
# Swap the p-values  with the formatted version from our apa_print() object IMPORTANT
M2table[2,6] <- as.character(ManCheck2.1APA$table$p[2])
M2table[1,6] <- as.character(ManCheck2.1APA$table$p[1])
M2table[3,6] <- as.character(ManCheck2.1APA$table$p[3])
# Rename the rows
M2table[ ,1] <- c("Company Motive", "CSR", "Company Motive * CSR", "Error")
colnames(M2table) <- c("Predictor", "$SS$", "$df$", "$MS$", "$F$", "$p$",
"$\\eta^{2}_{partial}$", "$\\eta^{2}_{partial}$ 95\\% CI")
```

And this is the code chunk that shows the table in my knitted document.

```r
apa_table(M2table, caption = "Effects of self- (versus other-oriented motive) and high CSR (versus neutral CSR) on perceived company motive", note = "Significant effects are bold", align = c("l", "r", "r", "r", "r", "r", "r", "c"), escape = F, row.names = F, # after manipulating the data frame, apa_table() started to show # the row numbers, so we had to choose "rownames = F" placement= "h")
```

Comment: can you add sample data so we could help u achieve the desired output?

Comment: Sorry about that! I added sample data as well as 2 packages I think were needed.

Comment: do you want to **embolden the full line** or just the name

Answer (score 1):

If you want to embolden only the predictor names then this will suffice:

```r
M2table <- M2$table_body

M2table[ ,1] <- c("", "Company Motive", "CSR", "Company Motive * CSR", "Error")
cond <- M2table$p != "" & as.numeric(M2table$p)<.01 
M2table[cond,1] <- paste0("\\textbf{",M2table[cond,1] ,"}")
M2table <- M2table[-1, ]
# Rename the rows
# Swap the p-values  with the formatted version from our apa_print() object IMPORTANT
m2table[1:3, 6] <- ManCheck2.1APA$table$p

colnames(M2table) <- c("Predictor", "$SS$", "$df$", "$MS$", "$F$", "$p$",
"$\\eta^{2}_{partial}$", "$\\eta^{2}_{partial}$ 95\\% CI")
```

[image]